# getting empty array and nothing else

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

get request here is just returning an empty array.  I cannot figure out why.  I've seen others code that looks the exact same work just fine.

I've tried googling the issue but haven't seen relevant answers.  I'm using Postman to test it.

```
const getPantry = async (req, res) => {
    const results = await pantry.find({});
    return send(res, 200, results)
}


module.exports = cors(
    router(
        get('/pantry', getPantry),
    )
)
```

I'm expecting a json object but it's just returning the empty array.

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but do you have data in the `pantry` collection?

Comment: Not stupid at all.  I do, but I determined that for whatever reason micro was simply not working on my machine.  Guess I should close this.

Answer (score 0):

The shortest quick and dirty complete working code I can get based on your example is this:

```
const { send } = require('micro')
const { router, get } = require('microrouter')
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb')

var pantry = null

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost')
  .then(conn => {
    pantry = conn.db('test').collection('pantry')
  })

const getPantry = async (req, res) => {
  const results = await pantry.find({}).toArray();
  send(res, 200, results)
}

module.exports = router(get('/pantry', getPantry))
```

Calling the endpoint using `curl`:

```
$ curl 'http://localhost:3000/pantry'
[{"_id":0},{"_id":1},{"_id":2}]
```

Which correctly shows the content of the collection.

I believe what is missing from your code is the `toArray()` method. `find()` by itself [returns a cursor](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.2/api/Collection.html#find) and it won't output the query result unless you do something with it, like calling `toArray()` or iterating on it using `forEach()`